# Get and set top position

Tags: javascript, jquery, hammer.js

I am using `hammer.js` to make a basic touch friendly mobile site. I have hidden the top menu with a negative top position and it will appear using css3 transitions upon a double tap. However I want it to then hide again upon a second double tap.

I have tried using `if/else` to call the top position then re-set it accordingly but I cant get it to work, anyone know where I am going wrong?

```
var t = $("#topbar");
var position = t.position();

$sw.on('doubletap', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (position.top == '-55px') {
        $('#topbar').css("top", "0");
    }
    else {
        $('#topbar').css("top", "-55px")
    }
});
```

The site address is http://www.bettondesignwork.co.uk/tim/mobile

Thanks

Comment: Am I missing something or `position = t.position()` should be in the event handler and not outside it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
var t = $("#topbar");
var position = t.offset();

$sw.on('doubletap', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (position.top == '-55px') {
        $("#topbar").offset({ top: "0"});
    }
    else {
        $('#topbar').offset({ top: "-55px"});
    }
}​
```

Comment: this has fixed my first problem of the whole thing not working so thank you very much, however once the menu has appeared, the second double tap to hide it again doesn't do anything?

Comment: @TimWilkinson Check @sawe's answer. Also, you could put `console.log( position.top );` inside your event to check what the value is at a given time ( and how it is presented ). Of course you might want to change it to click event for testing that in desktop.

Comment: it is set up to recognize mouse clicks as touch events for browser testing. still cant get the menu to hide again. is there a way of resetting the variables after each script run?

Comment: @TimWilkinson I was just writing about that, but couldn't edit my comment anymore. Was able to update my link though, check that out if you didn't see that v2 yet ( above your comment ). Your `position` variable is outside the event. So if you place the variable inside the event, it checks the offset each time the event is triggered.

Answer (score 2):

The problem could be this line

```
if (position.top == '-55px')
```

If i'm not mistaken, the .top property is numeric, so u could change the code to

```
if (position.top == -55)
```

Or become more defensive

```
if (position.top < 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Gets top position of one **HTMLElement**

```
   function getHTMLElementTop(thisNode, Top)
    {
            if (Top == undefined)
            {
                var Top = 0;
            }
            if (thisNode.nodeType == 1)
            {
                Top += thisNode.offsetTop;
                //if (thisNode.parentNode)
                if (thisNode.offsetParent)
                {
                    Top = getHTMLElementTop(thisNode.offsetParent, Top);
                }
            }
            return Top;
    }
```

May be it helps